# Store computation results in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, storage

How useful is it to store "simple" computation results in a (sql)-database?

Lets make an example:

- The gross price is: 10.00$
- Taxes are: 20%
- Shipping costs are: 5.00$

From these informations i can compute the:

- Net price: 12.00$
- Overall costs: 17.00$

The question is: Should i only store the 3 raw values and compute the other 2 on every request or should i compute them once and store them too?

In other words: What is more more valuable? Computation power or storage space?

Comment: The main reason i would not store the computed results is that taxes and shipping cost may vary over time, so these results become obsolete, or worse: wrong. A reason to still store them would be simpler / faster queries. But for your example, i strongly suggest you compute them on the fly when you need them.

Comment: But consider situation when taxes have to stay at value where it was at time of creation. Is that this situation? Is the price for goods in stock (so taxes should changes when laws changes), or it's just a record which stores finished order?

Comment: I would keep a computed answer only if there is a need to search by its value, because you can't make an index on a computed value, or if recomputing it would require accessing other large tables.

Comment: If you decide that you need to keep a (trivially) computed value, you should consider using a trigger to compute it so that you keep the computation in a single place.

Comment: It would be simpler to use generated columns functionality of mysql available from v5.7.6 or use views.

Comment: @RyanVincent many ERP systems do store net and gross amounts and the tax rate for transactions for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

To your question:

> In other words: What is more more valuable? Computation power or
>   storage space?

To answer this, you need to consider the use case of your data, and the trade-offs you are willing to make with speed and storage.

Consider the use case where there are 100 million records, and you need to run reports frequently which queries for Net Price, Overall costs.  In this case, your reports will run slower if the values are computed.  Now, If you need the reports to run faster, you can consider storing the computed values in the table.

As another use case, if you have the above data, and you have an audit table which stores every update to the data, and there are archive jobs that backup the data periodically, you will end up storing more data when the computed values are also part of the main table.

So the answer really depends on your use case and the trade-offs you are willing to make.